# Passing variables between two scripts

Tags: python, user-interface, multiprocessing, subprocess

So I'm new at multiprocessing and subprocessing and I am not sure if I am doing it right.

I have two scripts. One runs the main GUI, and has buttons that run other scrips. I want my entry boxes to be read by my other script, so that it can change the axis of a graph.For now, I simplified it so that it can print it so I can see that the values are being passed to begin with.
When I run the scrips like this:

```
###class_testing.py### (main script)
class Amplifier_Data_Analysis:

    def saving_graph_stuff(self):
        global int_startfreq,int_stopfreq,float_steps,float_add_tick

        STARTFREQUENCY = self.Start_Freq.get()
        int_startfreq  = int(STARTFREQUENCY)
        STOPFREQUENCY  = self.Stop_Freq.get()
        int_stopfreq   = int(STOPFREQUENCY)
        STEPS          = self.Steps.get()
        float_steps    = float(STEPS)
        ADD_TICK       = self.Add_Tick.get()
        float_add_tick = float(ADD_TICK)

        print(int_startfreq,int_stopfreq,float_steps,float_add_tick)
        return int_startfreq,int_stopfreq,float_steps,float_add_tick


    def testreport(self):
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,'test.py'])


###test.py###
from class_testing import *

int_startfreq,int_stopfreq,float_steps,float_add_tick = Amplifier_Data_Analysis.saving_graph_stuff()

print(startfrequency)
print(stopfrequency)
```

I get

```
int_startfreq,int_stopfreq,float_steps,float_add_tick = Amplifier_Data_Analysis.saving_graph_stuff()
TypeError: saving_graph_stuff() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

But when I put self, It says it is not defined which makes sense since it's a different script from the main. The GUI is generated form the PAGE app so it's very lengthy, but this is how it looks like: [GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2zMB.png)

How do I pass or read variables between two scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a class - you have to initialize it

```
int_startfreq,int_stopfreq,float_steps,float_add_tick = Amplifier_Data_Analysis().saving_graph_stuff()
```

Comment: This gets rid of the previous error. However, it now gives me "NoneType' object has no attribute 'geometry'. That is because in the same class, there is an __init__ function and it has this:'top.geometry("1188x984+389+1") ' among other GUI stuff like titles and colors. I know it's the class initialization in test.py because when I put an int, or character inside, it throws type errors. Is there a way to initialize it?

Comment: what class? try posting it in another question